# Longest common subsequence — recursion and memoization

Tags: recursion, rust, memoization

```rust
use std::{cmp::max_by_key, collections::HashMap};

fn longest_common_subsequence(s1: Vec<u8>, s2: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    struct Helper {
        s1: Vec<u8>,
        s2: Vec<u8>,
        cache: HashMap<(usize, usize), Vec<u8>>,
    }
    impl Helper {
        fn helper(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
            if self.cache.contains_key(&(i, j)) {
                return self.cache[&(i, j)].clone();
            }
            let value = {
                if i >= self.s1.len() || j >= self.s2.len() {
                    Vec::new()
                } else if self.s1[i] == self.s2[j] {
                    let mut tmp = vec![self.s1[i]];
                    tmp.append(&mut self.helper(i + 1, j + 1));
                    tmp
                } else {
                    max_by_key(self.helper(i + 1, j), self.helper(i, j + 1), |s| s.len())
                }
            };
            self.cache.insert((i, j), value.clone());
            return value;
        }
    }
    return Helper {
        s1,
        s2,
        cache: HashMap::new(),
    }
    .helper(0, 0);
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "{}",
        String::from_utf8(longest_common_subsequence(
            String::from("abcd").into_bytes(),
            String::from("adfsfsdfbcd").into_bytes()
        ))
        .unwrap()
    );
}
```

I'm playing around with Rust (only a few days into it) for a toy project in which I had to find the canonical representation for a given term -- I figured longest common subsequence of first few Google search results (titles) might do the trick, so I started implementing it and this is what I have (from a mental translation of how I'd do it in Python).

Among other things, it looks.. ugly to me. What can I do better (shorter / more readable e.t.c.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code *looks* dense because you've stuffed a lot of stuff into a single function, without any structuring whitespace. But that is merely cosmetic and can be fixed. For example, you might structure the code with some blank lines …

```rust
fn longest_common_subsequence(s1: Vec<u8>, s2: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    return Helper {
        s1,
        s2,
        cache: HashMap::new(),
    }
    .helper(0, 0);

    struct Helper { ... }

    impl Helper { ...  }
}
```

… or move the helper outside entirely:

```rust
fn longest_common_subsequence(s1: Vec<u8>, s2: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    Helper {
        s1,
        s2,
        cache: HashMap::new(),
    }
    .helper(0, 0)
}

struct Helper { ... }

impl Helper { ...  }
```

I've thought about whether a separate `Helper` struct even makes sense. In principle, you could just pass the values like the cache as arguments to a helper function, but given the pair of vecs `s1, s2` that should be kept together a struct makes sense. Often, the alternative would be to simply use a closure, but we can't directly have recursive closures.

A different debate can be had about whether the `helper()` function should be a *method*. I'd argue “no” – this is a purely syntactic choice here, and we could instead write the helper function to take a `&mut Helper` parameter. But that is primarily opinion-based.

When I look into the helper() implementation, I note this pattern:

```rust
if self.cache.contains_key(&(i, j)) {
    return self.cache[&(i, j)].clone();
}
```

This unnecessarily makes two accesses to the cache. Instead, we can write:

```rust
if let Some(value) = self.cache.get(&(i, j)) {
    return value.clone();
}
```

The `get()` method returns an `Option<&_>`, which we can pattern-match using `if let`.

Next, we have the pattern

```rust
if let Some(value) = self.cache.get(&(i, j)) {
    return value.clone();
}
let value = ...;
self.cache.insert(&(i, j), value.clone());
value
```

Again, the `get()` and `insert()` accesses do duplicate work. Typically, we can avoid this using the [HashMap Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry). An entry gives access to a slot in the hash map which may be occupied or may be vacant, and we can efficiently insert a value. The inserting function will return a reference to the value in either case, which we can clone:

```rust
self.cache.entry((i, j)).or_insert_with(|| ... ).clone()
```

which is very elegant **except** that this doesn't work here: the entry() keeps a `&mut` reference to the `self` Helper so that it can insert an item, but the closure also wants to borrow `self`. For that reason, it makes sense stick with your general design – but note that this could be avoided by using a different type for the cache, e.g. a Vec instead of a HashMap. A Vec or slice can be `split_at()` so that different sub-ranges can be borrowed separately. The problem as a whole is also amenable to using Dynamic Programming instead of memoization: without recursion, we wouldn't have to hold on to the cache for the duration of the recursive calls.

This is a common theme with Rust: things seem like they should be easy, but they're not that easy when thinking about the actual ownership or safety issues.

For example, I was thinking about returning a `&[u8]` from the helper() function to avoid unnecessary copies. This mostly works and saves a wasted allocation in the `tmp.append(...)` statement, but will ultimately have little effect since the `max_by_key(...)` statement has *two* calls into helper(). If their return value were to borrow the Helper struct, they would conflict with each other. In this particular case, it's also not possible to break the `&mut` requirement unless we put the cache into a `RefCell` and guarantee that the vec contents won't be moved, which we could do with a `Pin` and a bit of `unsafe` code.

In order to avoid excessive Vec copies, an alternative to references would be to track indexes into an array. This is a common strategy in Rust to avoid lifetime issues. Instead of

```rust
struct Helper {
  ...
  cache: HashMap<(usize, usize), Vec<u8>>,
}
```

we might use:

```rust
struct Helper {
  ...
  cache: HashMap<(usize, usize), usize>,
  subseqs: Vec<Vec<u8>>,
}
```

Then:

```rust
fn longest_common_subsequence(s1: Vec<u8>, s2: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut helper = Helper {
        s1,
        s2,
        cache: HashMap::new(),
        subseqs: vec![Vec::new()],
    };
    let result_index = helper.cached_value_for(0, 0);
    helper.subseqs[result_index].clone()
}

impl Helper {
    fn cached_value_for(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize) -> usize {
        if let Some(&value) = self.cache.get(&(i, j)) {
            return value;
        }
        
        let value = self.computed_value_for(i, j);
        self.cache.insert((i, j), value);
        value
    }
    
    fn computed_value_for(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize) -> usize {
        if i >= self.s1.len() || j >= self.s2.len() {
            return 0;
        }
        
        if self.s1[i] == self.s2[j] {
            let next_index = self.cached_value_for(i + 1, j + 1);
            let mut tmp = vec![self.s1[i]];
            tmp.extend_from_slice(&self.subseqs[next_index]);
            self.subseqs.push(tmp);
            return self.subseqs.len() - 1;
        }
        
        max_by_key(
            self.cached_value_for(i + 1, j),
            self.cached_value_for(i, j + 1),
            |&s| self.subseqs[s].len(),
        )
    }
}
```

The above code also separates the value construction from cache management. If desired, we could use this to eliminate the recursion by priming the cache in the correct pattern:

```rust
for i in (0..s1.len()).rev() {
    for j in (0..s2.len()).rev() {
        cache.insert((i, j), ...);
    }
}
```

A disadvantage of using indices instead of references is that we lose type safety: all those `usize` values look the same. This can be often be adressed with crates like [`typed-arena`](https://crates.io/crates/typed-arena).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!